# c++ negative number comparison

Tags: c++

why does this code below give the correct output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int max=0;
string k ="hello";
if(k.length()>max){
    max = k.length();
}
    cout<<max;
}
```

but this code below doesn't?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int max=-1;
string k ="hello";
if(k.length()>max){
    max = k.length();
}
    cout<<max;
}
```

Comment: there might be some issue with integer promotion

Comment: Check in the documentation what type is returned by `k.length()` and then check what happens when comparing this type with `int` (the type of `max`

Comment: The value `-1` converted to `unsigned` yields something like positive 4 billion something. You are not comparing negative numbers!

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to type conversion. Your max may be conversion to unsigned because k.lenght is unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to compare the `max` with `k.length()` by explicit conversion, it'll work.

The `k.length()` will return you `unsigned long long`, but the `max` was `signed int`. It might be the reason of the error. To solve it, let's do something like:

Look at the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int max = -1;
    string k ="hello";

    if(int(k.length()) > max) // use int()
        max = k.length();

    cout << max;
}
```

In other words, both the sides of comparison should be the same for a successful comparison.